# ROW_NUMBER with Parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. My procedure is

```
SELECT ContractorID ,
       Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ContractorID) as RowNumber
FROM dbo.Contractor
```

This is working but now I want to pass parameter into the `OVER` function.

I have tried :

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @OrderBy = 'ORDER BY ContractorID'

SELECT ContractorID ,
       Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (@OrderBy) as RowNumber
FROM dbo.Contractor
```

this gives the error 'incorrect syntax near @OrderBy'? How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905910(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: You can't parameterize column (or table) names or other keywords in T-SQL. In much the same way that you wouldn't expect in C# to be able to invoke a function just by having it's name in a string (yes, you can use Reflection, but it's not just a case of having the string and magically expecting it to invoke the function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a dynamic SQL and then execute it

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @OrderBy = 'ORDER BY ContractorID'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT ContractorID ,
       Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (' + @OrderBy + ') as RowNumber
FROM dbo.Contractor '

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: The syntax is slightly wrong at the end. It should be `EXEC (@SQL)` (the brackets are important). Alternatively it could be like in @Devart's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @OrderBy = 'ORDER BY ContractorID'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ContractorID ,
       Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (' + @OrderBy + ') as RowNumber
FROM dbo.Contractor'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score -1):

why not try this..

```
DECLARE @OrderBy VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @OrderBy = 'ContractorID'

SELECT ContractorID ,
       Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by @OrderBy) as RowNumber
FROM dbo.Contractor
```

hope this helps..

Comment: That will essentially add a column containing the same literal value of `'ContractorID'` to all rows then order by that. As the string is the same in all rows the resulting `ORDER BY` will be arbitrary.